# Pipe: How do I ensure if I successfully write into the pipe?

Tags: c, linux, pipe

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 50

struct record {
    int freq;
    char word[SIZE];
};

int main(){

int number_process = 3;
int pipes[number_process][2];

struct record r1;
r1.freq = 10;
strcpy(r1.word, "Cat");

struct record r2;
r2.freq = 20;
strcpy(r2.word, "Elephant");

struct record r3;
r3.freq = 30;
strcpy(r3.word, "Dragon");

struct record records_array[3] = {r1, r2, r3}; 

for (int i = 0; i < number_process; i++){

    if (pipe(pipes[i]) == -1){
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Create children.
    pid_t fork_result = fork();
    if (fork_result == -1){
        perror("Parent fork");
        exit(1);
    } else if (fork_result == 0){

        if (close(pipes[i][0]) == -1){
            perror("Child closes reading port");
            exit(1);
        }

        // Later children is going to close all reading port from pipe that parent creates.
        for (int child_no = 0; child_no < i; child_no++) {
            if (close(pipes[child_no][0]) == -1) {
                perror("close reading ends of previously forked children");
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        // Now, I am trying to write each strct record member from the above array into the pipe
        // when I run the program, it won't allow me to do so because of bad file descriptor exception.
        for (int j = 0; j < number_process; i++){
            if (write(pipes[i][1], &(records_array[j]), sizeof(struct record)) == -1){
                perror("write from child to pipe");
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        // Finishing writing, close the writing end in pipe.
        if (close(pipes[i][1]) == -1){
            perror("Child closes writing port");
            exit(1);
        }
        // Terminate the process.
        exit(0);

    } else {
        // Parent is closing all the writing ends in pipe.
        if (close(pipes[i][1]) == -1){
            perror("Parent close writing");
            exit(1);
        }

    }

}

struct record buffer;

for (int i = 0; i < number_process; i++){
    // Parent reads from the pipe.
    if (read(pipes[i][0], &buffer, sizeof(struct record)) == -1){
        perror("parent read");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("buffer.freq = %d\n", buffer.freq);
    printf("buffer.word = %s\n", buffer.word);

}


    return 0;
```

}

I am new to system programming, the following code is some practice I implement to see the pipe functionality. I have a few questions to my code:

1) Is there any system call or library call that will help me to ensure the content that I want to write into the pipe has actually been successfully written into the pipe? In other words, is there any methods available for me to check the content/data I wrote into the pipe?

2) I feel my parent reading part is not implemented correct, when I run this code, my parent reading part reads consecutive 3 same things, although it should be different things each time it read.

3) I have confronted the bad addresses issue when I try to read something from the pipe in my parent process, what is the reason that this error occurs?

Can someone please help me understand this stuff? Really appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55219339/pipe-bad-file-descriptors/55221440

Comment: I posted that actually, but in this post I would like to know more if there's actually any concrete ways that will help me check the pipe process.

Comment: If `write` returns a value other than `-1`, then your data was written into the pipe successfully.  As for question 2, your parent is reading the same thing because you incremented the wrong variable and wrote the same data multiple times.  As for question 3; the reason this occurs is that you are incrementing the wrong variable.  There's nothing esoteric happening.  A simple error is making things go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a simple cut-n-paste error.  `for (int j = 0; j < number_process; i++){`

You need to increment `j`.

Comment: Yes that's my bad